# draw color space conversion cubic with script

Tags: scripting

I wish to draw a color space conversion cubic with script.
reference output as below:

[image]

The inner cubic formula is:
[image]

The surface color is calculated from the formula as well. I have some python knowledge but a little bit blender script!
Many thanks if anyone can give some instruction! it's awesome if any recommend tutorials!

Comment: What do you want to represent in Blender? Blender is not design for showing sciences chart and figure but modeling project. The easiest one might be using **OSL node** in experiment Cycles render engine. Or you can use math node to do the linear algebra.

Comment: I wish to use blender to show details between two cubic,zoomin/zoomout/rotation freely. if it's not good to use blender! then I have to giveup. I guess it's easy to write a script to do that. if we only care about the shape but no color, is it easy for blender script?